# How to skip "Welcome Page" in Chrome using adb

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb

I am trying to open a URL in Google Chrome using adb command line. Have set "--no-first-run" using following command -

```
adb shell 'echo "chrome --no-first-run" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'
```

Have taken the command line switch from the following website - http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Then I execute the following commands,

```
adb -s TA99300UFC shell am set-debug-app com.android.chrome
adb -s TA99300UFC shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d 'http://wikipedia.org'
```

Still the "Welcome Page" shows up.

How can I skip this and go directly to the website URL passed in command?

Answer (score 11):

```
adb shell 'echo "chrome --disable-fre --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'
```

this command disables the welcome screen for chrome

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect for me, though the 'set-debug-app -- persistent com.android.chrome' one did.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was solved after the `--persistent` flag was added in the `set-debug-app` command.

So the command changed to `adb -s TA99300UFC shell am set-debug-app --persistent com.android.chrome`. After that `chrome://version` displayed `chrome --display-fre` under the `Command line` section.

Comment: tried the same as suggested but the chrome welcome to chrome screen did not go away.

Comment: 7 years later and this solves my problem.  Thank you StackOverflow for not archiving old questions.

Comment: Almost 9 years later and this till works like a charm for headless AVD :)

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this question when I was trying to **somehow** skip the welcome page. I finally managed to do so by using following code:

```
String context = driver.getContext(); // = "CHROMIUM"
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/terms_accept")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/negative_button")).click();
driver.context(context);
```

You have to switch into the context "NATIVE_APP" before you can click any buttons in Chrome that do not belong to a web page but rather belong to Chrome itself. Afterward you have to switch back out again by callling driver.context(context).

Hopefully I solved somebody's problem who also stumbled upon this page via Google.

Answer (score 0):

The `set-debug-app` solution is relatively ugly, it asks the system to start the application breakpointed, waiting for a debugger to attach. Using it to disable an application is not ideal.

I found that for my use-case, disabling the app worked just fine:

```
adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 org.chromium.chrome
```

This disables chrome for the user `0`, which is the main user of the device. You can list users using `adb shell pm list users`.

You can then re-enable the app using:

```
adb shell pm enable org.chromium.chrome
```

I also had issues that sometimes the change would not be taken into account after a reboot. It seems that `adb reboot` will not flush all writes to the disk in all cases, I found that asking for a clean reboot using:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.REBOOT
```

worked in all the cases.

Also note that the way to disable app has changed multiple times over android versions, I'm listing the more recent version as of now, find a more exhaustive list here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208271/141551