# Android skip chrome welcome screen using adb

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to skip the chrome welcome screen when running tests. The problem is other solutions that I have found like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408138/how-to-skip-welcome-page-in-chrome-using-adb) don't seem to work anymore.

Commands used:

```
$ adb shell pm clear com.android.chrome 

$ adb shell 'echo "chrome --disable-fre --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'

$ adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was actually a combination of the question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416846/807825). The solution can also be found in [another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33418195/807825), though it's not entirely clear.

The following should work:

```
$ adb shell am set-debug-app --persistent com.android.chrome 
$ adb shell 'echo "chrome --disable-fre --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'
$ adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

Some notes:

1. In the [Chromium project documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags#TOC-Android), it's mentioned that for the command line file to be used, the user should

> "Enable command line on non-rooted devices" in chrome://flags

Setting Chrome as the debug application replaces this requirement.

2. In older device versions, the command line file was expected in `/data/local`. This folder is no longer writable from adb shell in non-rooted devices, so `/data/local/tmp` should be used instead. This is documented in [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=561796)
3. In the [ChromeSwitches.java current source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/flags/android/java_templates/ChromeSwitches.java.tmpl), only `--disable-fre` still exists. The other flags might be required in older Chrome versions, but I didn't verify.

Comment: The line: `adb shell 'echo "chrome --disable-fre --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'` is required for older Android devices, I can confirm Android 6.

Comment: adding this at first do the job "pm clear com.android.chrome"

Answer (score 5):

What is your OS version? It is working on Android 10. You can try the below commands:

```sh
$ adb shell pm clear com.android.chrome 
$ adb shell am set-debug-app --persistent com.android.chrome
$ adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```